# raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, communityengine

```
  def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
    raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)
  end

  def load_schema_if_pending!
```

i have  run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development but still nothing happens, i was trying to add community engine to my rails 4.2 app, help anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the [installation instructions](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine#getting-communityengine-running) you need to run `rake community_engine:install:migrations` before `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: i get error after i run rake db:migrate  
== 20161025101744 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table("users")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,

Comment: I had to drop class from SQLite on cl and run rake db:migrate